# Usar Header de outro site WordPress

Tags: php, html5, wordpress, header

Preciso desenvolver um site em WordPress, onde eu tenha que usar o header (menu) de um outro site também em WordPress.
Uma solução que achei, foi embedar o mesmo via Iframe, porém, teria um *delay* um pouquinho diferente dos demais conteúdos do site. 
Existe uma outra alternativa para isso?

Comment: Outro site == site que está hospedado em outro lugar, ao qual você não tem acesso?

Comment: Sim, esta em ouro domínio, porém, tenho acesso ao conteúdo do mesmo.

Comment: e você não pode hospedar esse header novo no seu site?  fazer um arquivo `header-novoheader.php` e fazer a chamada `get_header('novoheader')`?

Comment: Mas caso eu faça isso, ele vai pegar todo conteúdo dinâmico deste site original mesmo estando fora da estrutura original?

Comment: não, por isso que eu perguntei

Comment: Puts.. Precisaria usar a mesma estrutura de Header utilizada em outro tema, e coloca-la como sendo meu header neste novo site... Tenho acesso ao conteúdo mas não sei outra alternativa a não ser via iframe..

Comment: Se você quer que as mudanças persistam de um site pro outro, o buraco é mais fundo, acredito. Vou dar uma pensada aqui

Comment: beleza... Eu ainda não achei uma solução plausível :(

Answer (score 0):

Não vou dizer que é impossível, mas não consigo visualizar nenhuma maneira pra fazer isso de forma nativa no WP... se fosse algum conteúdo específico, como um menu ou post até daria.

Acho que tem que ser iframe mesmo, a solução que pensei é fazer uma imagem que fica por cima do iframe, o mais parecida possível ao conteúdo que vai puxar do outro site. Uma vez carregado esse conteúdo no iframe, fazer um fade da imagem e mostrar o iframe. A imagem precisa ser removida também, senão bloqueia a interação com o iframe.

Dependendo da arte gráfica da imagem e da semelhança com o conteúdo do iframe, fica bem razoável a transição.

Fiz esta prova de conceito, não dá para colocar como Stack Snippet ou JSFiddle pois não aceitam mostrar iframes. Neste teste, o conteúdo é o site do JSFiddle (que aceitou funcionar dentro de um iframe) e a imagem é um [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otse0.png) que fiz do iframe carregado na página de teste.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        #imagem {
            z-index:10;
            background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otse0.png");
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #menu {
            z-index:1;
            width: 400px;
            height: 250px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Teste iframe com transição ao carregar</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function fadeOut( el, duration ) {
            /**
             * @author: http://stackoverflow.com/a/867620/1287812
             * @param el - Elemento para fazer fadeout.
             * @param duration - Duração da animação em milisegundos.
             */
            var step = 10 / duration,
                opacity = 1;
            function next() {
                if (opacity <= 0) { return; }
                el.style.opacity = ( opacity -= step );
                setTimeout(next, 10);
            }
            next();
        }    
        function remove( id ) {
            /* @author: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3391282/1287812 */
            return (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            var oIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
            oIframe.onload = function() {
                var image = document.getElementById('imagem');
                fadeOut(image, 500);
                // Remover a imagem um pouco depois do fade 
                setTimeout(function(){ remove('imagem'); },600);
            }
            oIframe.src = 'https://jsfiddle.net/';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="frame-total">
        <div id="imagem"></div>
        <div id="menu">
            <iframe id="iframe" src="" width="400" height="250" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

<sup>Artigo interessante que encontrei enquanto pesquisava: [*Iframe loading techniques and performance*](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance?%3E)</sup>